# Excel: Writing formula to determine when values in a range to cross two threshold values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

The threshold values are <=-10 (lower threshold) and (upper threshold) >=10.

The thresholds only get crossed when, for the upper threshold, the previous value of a cell is <=-10 and the current cell is >=10. And for the lower threshold, the value in the previous cell is >=10 and the current cell is <=-10.

I will now show what crossing the upper threshold means.

For example, I have the cells:

```
A1 -6

A2 -98

A3 -83

A4 -74

A5 16
```

The upper threshold has been crossed since A4 is <=10 and A5 is greater than >=10.

For crossing the lower threshold requires the previous cell to be <=10 and the current cell to be <=-10, as stated above.

All other combinations of values in the previous and current cells cannot cause a crossing of either the upper or lower threshold.

I have been trying to use the formula:

```
IF(AND(A1>=10, A2<=-10), 1, IF(AND(A1<=-10, A2>=10), 2, IF(AND(A1<-10,A2<-10), 3, IF(AND(A1>10, A2>10), 4, IF(AND(-10<A1<10, -10<A2<10), 5, IF(AND(A1<=-10, A2<10), 6, IF(AND(A1>=10, A2>-10), 7, 8))))))
```

`IF(AND(A1>=10, A2<=-10), 1, IF(AND(A1<=-10, A2>=10), 2)` is supposed to represent what crossing the thresholds consists in.

`IF(AND(A1<-10, A2<-10), 3, IF(AND(A1>10, A2>10), 4, IF(AND(-10<A1<10, -10<A2<10), 5, IF(AND(A1<=-10, A2<10), 6, IF(AND(A1>=10, A2>-10), 7, 8)` is supposed to represent all the combinations of A1 and A2 that do not represent crossing the threshold and the false value of 8 is supposed to pick up any nonsense.

However, I get too few signals of the crossing of either threshold.

I do not know where I am going wrong. I understand there might be a more simplistic and concise formula to use, but as of yet, I haven't found one.

I can add further clarification if needed.

This is where basic's formula can go wrong with modified values in the A column:

As you can see, it does not err at b5 since the upper threshold has already been crossed, it errs at b9 since the lower threshold has been crossed, and errs again at b14 since the upper threshold has been crossed.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I need some more clarity. Are you saying that two consecutive values to must have at least one value in the range -10 to 10? What are the results that you want?

Comment: You should delete the comment with the incorrect spec. It's confusing.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you should delete a LOT of this question because quite a bit of it is self contradictory. Is "The thresholds only get crossed when, for the upper threshold, the previous value of a cell is <=-10 and the current cell is >=10. And for the lower threshold, the value in the previous cell is >=10 and the current cell is <=-10" actually true? Not based on your updated image.

Comment: I was going to give this a shot using one or two helper columns, but now I'm not. [edit] this question (do not ask it again), remove everything that's wrong or extraneous, then check it over again to make sure everything is stated clearly and correctly, and perhaps someone can help.

Comment: Please do not deface your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: Write https://superuser.com/contact and they can make your this question disassociated from your account, if you wish to. Alternatively, you can delete your this account (in your profile settings).

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the following formula will help you:

```
=CHOOSE((A1>=10)*(A2<=-10)+(A1<=-10)*(A2>=10)*2+1,0,-1,1)
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

Based on the extended conditions, the solution with helper column:

formula in `B` column -

```
=((A2<=-10)*-1+(A2>=10)=0)*B1+((A2<=-10)*-1+(A2>=10))
```

formula in `C` column -

```
=B2*(B2<>B1)
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: excellent solution! (A1>=10)*(A2<=-10) returns FALSE aka 0 if outside range criteria one and (A1<=-10)*(A2>=10) returns FALSE 0 if outside range two. The *2 gives the second test a different result than if the first test, and the +1 adjusts the possible outcomes up one so that 0, 1 ,2 becomes 1,2 or 3 which correspond to the returns values positions 1, 2,  3 which are 0, -1, 1. I'm not sure if my explanation helps or hurts lol, and I might be missing something

Comment: @Herodotous Then try to find a row where this formula doesn't work as expected and then we can look for another solution.

Comment: No, in comments you can post links only. But you can edit question and add picture there.

Comment: Then you have to look not only at the previous cell but at the entire column that there was no crossing before. It will be more complicated, I have to think.

Comment: @Herodotous Unfortunately, I can't figure out a solution with a single formula, but if you can use an helper column then look at the edited solution.